# How to manage a home-grown YUM package repo?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

There are plenty of websites that explain how to manage a mirror of YUM repos.  I want to run a repo for my home-grown packages.  Is there a good way to manage such repos?

What I need to do:

- Manage 3 repos: unstable, testing, stable
- Self-service functions that let users add/remove/promote packages (promote means moving a package unstable→testing or testing->stable).
- ACLs that control which users/groups may add/remove/promote packages.
- Automatically re-sign packages as they move repo to repo (since the GPG key for "stable" should be different than "unstable")
- Automatically run "createrepo" to update repodata when needed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FAS](https://fedorahosted.org/fas/), [Koji](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji), and [Bodhi](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bodhi) for this. They are a bit complex to set up, but should handle most of what you're looking for.

Comment: Complex is right: plan on spending an entire week setting this up and doing absolutely nothing else. But this really is the best option.

Comment: It sounds like only complex solutions are available.  I may write my own simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @TomOnTime Beware. I wrote my own little set of shell scripts for this, and it's quickly grown out of control at just two repos and three packages. So I'm in the midst of making this move myself. The future time savings alone will be worth it.